NDSolve returns bad interpolation but manually interpolating its samplings gives good result
I'm using NDSolve to get a ODE solution. The returned interpolation function has a large relative error at the early evolution stage.
What confuses me is that Reap[NDSolve[…, StepMonitor :> Sow[{t, Re[A[t]]}]]] returns a correct sampling which can be interpolated artificially. However, the artificial interpolation function is correct and the large local error occurring in NDSolve doesn't appear! I want to know why and What happened in NDSolve.
Someone may suspect NDSolve choose a wrong InterpolationOrder. However, whatever you set InterpolationOrder in NDSolve, you always get a large local error result which is  different from artificial interpolation object.
I also checked whether the interpolation function returned by NDSolve does pass through all sampling points. Yes, it does.
My code is
(*parameter and ODE*)
    k = 10^13;
    H = 10^-5;
    \[Chi][z_] := \[Pi]/4 + ArcTan[3/10 (34 - H*z)];
    \[ScriptA][z_] := E^(H*z);
    s4 = Reap[
         NDSolve[
         {A''[t] + ((\[ScriptA]'[t]/\[ScriptA][t] - 2 (I*k)/\[ScriptA][t])*A'[t] 
         + 20*k/\[ScriptA][t]*\[Chi]'[t] A[t]) == 0, A[0] == 1,A'[0] == 0},
         {A[t], A'[t]}, {t, 0, 65*10^5},
       Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}
         , StepMonitor :> Sow[{t, Re[A[t]]}]]];
(*Draw using sample points*) 
      ListPlot[s4[[2]][[1]], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
(*interpolate artificially*) 
       r = Interpolation[DeleteDuplicatesBy[s4[[2]][[1]], First]]
(*Draw using artificial interpolation object*) 
      Plot[{r[t]}, {t, 0, 65*10^5}, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5},  PlotStyle -> {Green}]
(*Draw using NDSolve interpolation function*)
      Plot[{Re[A[t] /. s4[[1]][[1]]]}, {t, 0, 65*10^5}, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> {Red}]
(*NDSolve interpolation function cross all samplings*)
      F[m_] := ((Re[A[t]]) /. s4[[1]][[1]]) /. t -> m
      ListPlot[Transpose[{Transpose[s4[[2]][[1]]][[1]], F[Transpose[s4[[2]][[1]]][[1]]]}], PlotRange -> All]
      ListPlot[s4[[2]][[1]], PlotRange -> All]

This is my result




I tried to increase WorkingPrecision, but it spends too much time and doesn't resolve this question. Because you will receive Maxstep warning after setting WorkingPrecision->30, and if you want to increase Maxstep->10^N, it is no hope. As the image show: a large step get a very short movement!


See a strange error change process (if the solution is correct, the value is nearly zero; more important, after divide 10^n, the error  changes so much) :


The magnitude of all terms in this ODEA:

Coefficient


Single terms





What should I do if I insist on using NDSolve and keep Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}} to get an interpolation function that is as good as manual interpolation

Have you tried e.g. "WorkingPrecision->30"?

What @mikado said. The terms in your ODE have magnitudes of 10^9, 10^14, 10^30 near the beginning. So you'll need a working precision quite a bit greater than 30-9 = 21. Unless you can scale your problem. Of course, that estimate is based on a poor solution, so it may be off. The solution uses the complex-valued first and second derivatives computed during the integration process to construct an interpolating polynomial between the steps. The numerical error in the second derivative is causing the error in the interpolation. Probably causes error in the solution, too, including r.

@mikado@Michael E2:well, I tried to increase working precision and accuracy goal ,but both give me a warning NDSolve::At t==2.246685732925871104147693098837502194838792562553`30.*^-10, the maximum number of steps, 10000, was reached.  In fact,spend a Large step which needs so many minutes but a very short
movement. You can try .It is not possible to increase the Maxstep option to resolve this message!

A less  WorkingPrecision（for example,29)-you can get result without so much steps but still has a large local error at early stage

@Michael E2: this ODE has three single terms (all is complex) : A''[t]，(a'[t]/a[t] - 2 (Ik)/a[t])A'[t],  20k/a[t][Chi]'[t] A[t] . As the picture shown , A''[t]=10^1+I* 10^0,(a'[t]/a[t] - 2 (Ik)/a[t])A'[t]=10^17+I10^17, 20k/a[t]\ [Chi]'[t]A[t]=10^16+I10^14.when I said this, I mean it is at the catastrophy happened.  why do you think “terms in my ODE have magnitudes of 10^9, 10^14, 10^30” ？when you said this, what location do you mean？ In fact，A'[t] and A''[t] at the start before the catastrophy happened is very small, magnitude is 10^-7 and 10^-8 .

I plugged the solution into the terms and plotted them. Actually, probably should ignore A''[t]. I guess I made two mistakes, the first being to use the bad interpolation. I mentioned that might be a problem, but it really is quite clear that it is not a valid analysis. However, A''[0] is roughly 5 x 10^6, not as small as you claim. (Solve the IC exactly.) Quickly, it falls below the AccuracyGoal of roughly 8, I think, which means that NDSolve won't worry about errors below that magnitude. So I think the values of A''[t] that are computed are not accurate and seem to mess up the interp.

@ Michael E2: I agree with your opinion that A‘’[0]=-20k/[ScriptA][0][Chi]'[t] A[0]=10^6. I also want to increase  Accuracygoal and  WorkingPrecision as you said，but when I do that，I always need a large step 10^7 even more ,when I had a lunch ，I found NDSolve still doesn’t reach 1（total range from 0 to 65*10^5).  More important ,Mathematica will quits kernel automatically if you set option AccuracyGoal -> 14, PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxSteps -> 10^6, WorkingPrecision -> 16, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching". It is not possible to increase the Maxstep option to get you said workingprecision

Just to make sure: the question focuses on the "why" part so work-arounds are not of interest, right?

@ xzczd: Thanks for your reminder.  My original purpose focuses on why, after chatting, I  am confused on how to solve this ODE by NDSolve. So I put another question just now.

Changing WorkingPrecision between MachinePrecision up to 50 does not make an obvious difference to me in the solution. (It makes a small difference in A[t]; but the error seems negligible, or at least I can't prove to myself that it matters.) If the steps are accurate, then this removes the A''[t] values from the interpolation, and it becomes smooth: s4IFN = A[t] /. First[s4] // Flatten // First // Head; solIFN = NestList[Derivative[1], s4IFN, 1]["ValuesOnGrid"] // Through //  Prepend[s4IFN["Grid"]] // Transpose // Interpolation

Actually if I set MaxStepSize -> 2000 or lower, the nature of the solution changes significantly.

@MichaelE2 I believe StiffnessSwitching is giving fake solution for small MaxStepSize. The default ODE solver (LSODA I guess?) with MaxStepSize->1000 and Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta"}}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], StartingStepSize -> 5 10^2 both result in that more oscillating solution.

Thanks :  It's your detailed answer makes me understand the second derivative value information destroyed this interpolation result and @MichaelE2 's comment. I still has three questions:1.since A''［t］is not accurate and participate in this ODE, why we can believe A[t] and A'[t]  are accurate (A[t],A'[t],A''[t] evolve together)

2.''Unless you can scale your problem''-this seems an alternative solution for me  to avoid  10^9 term to be eaten by large 10^30 term. i'm interested in how this achieved, Could you give me a clear explanation ,@ Michael E2, thanks

@MichaelE2 :Did you set method- stiffnessswitching? I'm corious about “ you changed  Workingprecision between  Machineprecisionup to 50” .I always receive Maxstep warning when I keep stiffnessswitching and a large  Workingprecision,and even I adjust a large Maxstep , I can't overcome this warning.

The code is gone now, so I can't be sure. I kept your Method. I probably fixed AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal at low values, like 6 or 8. I adjusted AccuracyGoal between 8 and 16 sometimes; above around 10 or 12, it would take many steps, maybe 10^6, and not get past t=10^-8. If you raise WorkingPrecision, it raises AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal, unless you fix them at a lower value.

You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. (See this post to learn the correct usage of @ ). Then, "why we can believe A[t] and A'[t] are accurate (A[t],A'[t],A''[t] evolve together)" I'm afraid you've misunderstood something about numeric ODE solving. Actually A''[t] isn't calculated directly like A[t] and A'[t] because it doesn't appear explicitly in the right hand side of stand form of ODE, see e.g. this post for more info.

This answer can be viewed as an extension of Michael E2's comments above. I fail to go deeper, but still decide to make this public in memory of my whole night.
First of all, I'd like to point out the following truth:
Derivative values may vastly influences the interpolating result of "Hermite" interpolation in an undesired way in certain situ.
Here's a minimal sample:
xmin = 0; xmax = 10^4; derivative2 = 10^-4;
pts = {{{xmin}, 0, 0, 0}, {{xmax}, 0, 0, derivative2}};

func = Interpolation[pts];
(* Just to show Interpolation is working in the expected way: *)
expr = InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x]
(* ((-10000 + x)^2 x^3)/20000000000000000 *)

GraphicsRow[{Plot[{func[x], expr}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "function"], 
  Plot[func''[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "2nd derivative of function"]}]


Clearly, usually the following interpolation is more desired:
funcAlt = Interpolation[Most /@ pts];
funcD2 = Interpolation[#[[{1, 4}]] & /@ pts];

GraphicsRow@{Plot[funcAlt[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "function"], 
  Plot[funcD2[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> "2nd derivative of function"]}


And this is what has happened in your sample.
So, if you "insist on using NDSolve and keep Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}} to get an interpolation function that is as good as manual interpolation", one possible work-around is to rebuild an interpolating function from the obtained interpolating function:
k = 10^13;
H = 1/10^5;
χ[z_] := π/4 + ArcTan[3/10 (34 - H z)];
\[ScriptA][z_] := E^(H z);
tend = 65 10^5;

sol = NDSolveValue[{A''[
       t] + ((\[ScriptA]'[t]/\[ScriptA][t] - 
           2 (I k)/\[ScriptA][t]) A'[t] + 
        20 k/\[ScriptA][t] χ'[t] A[t]) == 0, A[0] == 1, 
    A'[0] == 0}, A, {t, 0, tend}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}];

solnew = ListInterpolation[sol["ValuesOnGrid"], sol["Coordinates"]];

plot = ReImPlot[solnew[t], {t, 0, tend}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]


However, this isn't the end. At this point, it's natural to ask: is the interpolation error the only reason for the bad result? Is the value of derivative accurate enough? The answer seems to be "No".
By adjusting the xmax in first code sample, it's easy to notice that smaller xmax will result in smaller interpolation error:
xmin = 0; derivative2 = 10^-4;
mani = Table[
  pts = {{{xmin}, 0, 0, 0}, {{xmax}, 0, 0, derivative2}};
  func = Interpolation[pts];
  Plot[func[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> {0, 200}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(max\)]\): ", xmax}]], {xmax, 
   10^3, 10^4, 10^3}]

Export["a.gif", mani] // SystemOpen


This suggests that setting a smaller MaxStepSize for NDSolve may resolve the problem. Indeed, as shown under your subsequent question, this is true for the default ODE solver of NDSolve. But it's not true for Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}!:
solfake = 
   NDSolveValue[{A''[
        t] + ((\[ScriptA]'[t]/\[ScriptA][t] - 
            2 (I k)/\[ScriptA][t]) A'[t] + 
         20 k/\[ScriptA][t] \[Chi]'[t] A[t]) == 0, A[0] == 1, 
     A'[0] == 0}, A, {t, 0, tend}, 
    Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
      Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, 
    MaxStepSize -> 10^3]; // AbsoluteTiming

With[{sol = solfake}, 
 GraphicsRow[{ReImPlot[sol[t], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> 1.5], 
   With[{coord = sol["Coordinates"][[1]]}, 
    ListPlot[{{coord, Re[sol["ValuesOnGrid"]]}\[Transpose], {coord, 
        Im[sol["ValuesOnGrid"]]}\[Transpose]}, PlotRange -> All]]~Show~plot}]]


As we can see, MaxStepSize -> 10^3 doesn't save the day. Further check shows even MaxStepSize -> 10 won't save our day. What's more, the original data becomes incorrect around t == 10^6!
So it's reasonable to guess:

StiffnessSwitching method isn't robust on this problem. (BTW, though I can't recall any specific post at the moment, this is absolutely not the first time I see StiffnessSwitching giving fake result. So I myself won't turn to StiffnessSwitching method unless I have no other choice. )

Numeric error (probably numeric error of derivative) has played a significant role in ruining the interpolating result.


But how can we lower the numeric error of derivative? Why does the default ODE solver handle the problem so nicely? Sadly these are still open questions.
